# Как повторить запрос если вернулся 404 в jsonp? Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Здравствуйте, пишу код на Vanilla Js. Суть в том, что я получаю запросы с сервера используя jsonp, и иногда по неведанной мне причине прилетает 404. Вообщем надо повторить запрос если вдруг вылетит 404. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неплохо увидеть бы Ваш код.

Нет возможности узнать статус ответа, если загружается через тэг `script`.
Единственное, что можно сделать, это понять что загрузка неудачна.
У тэгов `script`, `img`, `link` и `iframe` можно установить коллбэки на `onload` и `onerror`:

```js
let jq = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(jq);

jq.onload  = _ => console.info("jQuery успешно загружен!");
jq.onerror = _ => console.info("Ошибка с jQuery!");


let _404 = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
_404.src = "https://example.com/_NotFoundScript.js";
document.body.appendChild(_404);

_404.onload  = _ => console.info("_404 успешно загружен о_О!");
_404.onerror = _ => console.info("Ошибка с _404!");
```

В теле коллбэка ошибки просто запускаем повтор запроса.

[В тему](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror).